# Rails route to angularjs gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, twitter

Could someone more experienced please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have this in my routes.rb:

```
resources :interests do
  resources :tweets, only: :index
end
```

In my TweetsController I have this index method:

```
 def index
   @tweets = get_user_tweets(params[:id])       
   respond_with(@tweets) do |format|
   format.json { render :json => @tweets.as_json }
  end end
```

The plan is, when I go to */interests/:id/tweets* to get the tweets json format, here is what I have in my app.js

```
app.factory('Tweets', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/interests/:id/tweets.json')
} ]);

app.controller("HomeCtrl", ['$scope','Interest','Tweets', '$routeParams', function($scope,Interest,Tweets, $routeParams) {
  $scope.interest = Interest.get({id: $routeParams.id})
  $scope.tweets = Tweets.query();
  $scope.works = "it works";
}]);
```

in the config:

```
$routeProvider.when('/interests/:id/tweets',{
            templateUrl: '/templates/tweets.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        });
```

But when I go to for example interests/4/tweets I get the message "it works" but I don't get the tweets, when I open the console it says **/interests/tweets.json 404 (Not Found)** which is wrong because it should look for *interests/:id/tweets*

Can someone please point me to the mistake I'm making?

```
app.factory('Interests', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/interests.json', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    }) 
}]);

app.factory('Interest', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/interests/:id.json', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
    }
```

)
}])

Comment: it's throwing this error because server thinks 'tweets' in _interests/tweets_ is an ID, so it cannot find an ID with value 'tweets', but I cant figure why is it searching that url when I gave it _interests/:id/tweets_ please help

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `Interest` in your `HomeCtrl`?

Comment: There, I added Interest, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> server thinks 'tweets' in interests/tweets is an ID, so it cannot find an ID with value 'tweets', but I cant figure why is it searching that url when I gave it interests/:id/tweets

That's because by calling the `query` method on your `Tweets` service you don't supply an `id`. In your controller you invoke it like that:

```
$scope.tweets = Tweets.query({id: 4});
```

Comment: Now I'm getting _/interests/tweets.json?interest_id=2 _ error , please note that I don't have a Tweets model, I get the tweets from Twitter API (application only authentication) and before I integrated Angularjs the app was working fine on html.erb, I filtered the tweets based on my interests (users) but sending that to angular (which I must do) is troubling me

Comment: it should be 'interests/interest_id/tweets

I'm doing it this way in order to get the info on the user and the tweets
maybe my approach is totally wrong, but I dont see another way...

Comment: And what if you use `get` instead of `query`

Comment: I am developing it with cloud9, if you have time you can check the code :)

Comment: awesome, yeah I guess, I never did it before :D